# Maven проект не видит мои тесты

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, maven

Java maven проект, при сборке mvn verify package тесты прогоняются как надо, при попытке mvn test( из компилатора или консоли) появляется строка

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ GreetTime ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

и сразу переходит к завершению.Стало быть мои тесты просто пропускаются, думаю что я где-то не так указал путь к нужной папке. Как сделать так что бы тесты запускались при команде `mvn test`. Потому что мне нужно в будущем будет запускать тесты при сборке ( Travis CI) , в данный момент просто не видит тесты.
При `mvn test -Dtest=IntegrationTest` все работает, но такой вариант не подходит.
При указании `<testClassesDirectory>Greeting\target\test-classes</testClassesDirectory>` получаю ошибку `no Tests to run`

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mavenTime</groupId>
<artifactId>GreetTime</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>GreetJar</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <log4j.version>1.2.12</log4j.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <testSourceDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</testSourceDirectory>
                <reportsDirectory>Greeting\target\surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>none</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IntegrationTest*.java</include>
                            <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                            <include>**/*IntegrationTest*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <testSourceDirectory>Greeting\target\surefire-reports</testSourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
    </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                         <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                         <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                         <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                     </manifest>
                 </archive>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <phase>package</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>single</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
             <configuration>
                 <archive>
                     <manifest>
                         <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                     </manifest>
                 </archive>
                 <descriptorRefs>
                     <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                 </descriptorRefs>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.3.2</version>
             <configuration>
                 <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                 <target>${jdk.version}</target>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>
 <dependencies>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>log4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
         <version>${log4j.version}</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.10</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
         <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                 <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                 <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 </project>
```

Comment: При созадния maven проекта создаються 2 субдеректории, `main/java` и `test/java` и  при запуске `package`,`tes`t или `install` mvn сканирует дирукторию `test` на наличие тестов и запускает их. И не требуеться не каких дополнительных манипуляций с конфигурацией pom-a

Comment: В чем тогда может быть проблема? ПРи mvn verify package все работает, при maven test ничего не происходит( Может что-то лишнее у меня в pom ?

Comment: Попрбоуйте удалить все конфиги связанные с тестами из pom-a и запустите заного. И да, почему путь к тестам указан на targer директорию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

попробуйте все тесты добавить в пакет **src/test/java**, сами классы тестов должны или начинаться с **Test** или заканчиваться на **Test**, например **TestMain** или **MainTest**. Плагин для мавена:

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Класс тест находится в папке src/test/java , плагин этот есть,слово ТЕСТ в классе присутствует, думаю искать лишние плагины и удалять, может конфликтуют.

Comment: попробуйте в настройках плагина в `<configuration>`  указать только `<skipTests>false</skipTests>`

Comment: Я поставил бы тебе 100 плюсов, но лишен такой возможности!!!Она ОЖИЛА!!!!!спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!